# what is the use of WSDL?

Tags: asp.net, wsdl

Sir/Madam,
I want to know where WSDL exists. Do user need to do interact with it for any kind of scenario during programing?

Comment: I always read that English people don't have proper English and found u as a perfect example. Didn't get what actually u wanted to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL stands for Web Service Description Language, it uses XML to define functions that a web service exposes and the types that these functions receive as arguments and return.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL

You can usually access the WSDL for a web service using a query string (in .NET web services at least). A developer usually won't look at the WSDL as it will be generated by a tool like Visual Studio or soapsuds and code will be generated to represent the types based on the definition in the WSDL that the developer will make use of instead. Changes to the WSDL will result in regeneration of this code.

Answer (score 3):

WSDL (Web Services Description Language) is an XML-based language for describing Web services and how to access them.

[Web Services Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)

Comment: kya isse aur chota answer bhi ho sakta hai?

Comment: this is enough to answer your question you can go to link and read more or you can go to msdn and read more detail

Comment: yes.. thats right. This answer could be helpful during interview session. Thank u very much.

Answer (score 2):

With respect, this is a bad question. You're in effect asking us to do your research for you. When I say "bad" what I mean here is that you're in danger of harming yourself by asking questions like this. If instead you do some preliminary research, for example by googling WSDL, and find resources such as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/default.asp) then you expose yourself to the "Encyclopedia Effect", you encounter other related (or indeed unrelated information) and you learn more. When you research and come across something you don't understand then you can ask specific questions in places like this, and you have a context to understand the answers. I truly believe that researching in the way I describe will be most helpful to you in the long term.

To give one answer to your questions: you will find examples of useful WSDLs [here](http://www.webservicelist.com/).

As a programmer you can develop service clients from those WSDLs, or more usually use code generators to write the "boilerplate" code for you.

If you want to provide your own services then you may write WSDLs your self.

Comment: thank u . But more than giving answer you explained me what to do and what not. Cool. Enjoy.

Comment: But I accept your valuable point of searching. Thanks a lot. Keep answering.